# How to watch the ngForm change and do the calculation based on the changed value

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, angular-reactive-forms, reactive

I failed to get the changed input value from a reactive ngForm and unable to do the calculation based. Please see my requirement as showed in the screenshot.

[image]
form code:

```html
<form #adForm="ngForm" (onSubmit)="onSubmit(adForm)">
    <table  class="table text-center">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col"><div class="align-middle">#</div></th>
          <th scope="col"><div class="align-middle">MonthlyFee</div></th>
          <th scope="col"><div class="align-middle">Months</div></th>
          <th scope="col"><div class="align-middle">Total Fee</div></th>
          <th scope="col"><div class="align-middle">Confirm</div></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="border_bottom">          
          <td class="align-middle">123</td>
          <td class="align-middle">{{ads.price | currency}}</td>
          <td class="align-middle">
            <input 
              type="number" min="1" max="12"              
              required
              class="form-control ml-4"
              id="months"
              placeholder="{{0}}"
              name="months"  
              [(ngModel)]="ads.months"            
            >
          </td>
          <td class="align-middle">{{ads.adsFee}}</td>    
          <td class="align-middle">      
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="onCreate()">Create</button>
          </td>           
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
```

in ts, would expect the simple calculation:
totalFee = price * months;

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nyvclu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html this way you can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply like that:

```
<td class="align-middle">{{ads.price * ads.months | currency}}</td>
```